# How can I check streaks by team and by result using mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have created a View that includes the match id, team, result (using "W", "D", "L") and date. 
e.g.:

```
'32750', 'Team 1', 'D', '2019-02-16 21:30:00'
'32750', 'Team 2', 'D', '2019-02-16 21:30:00'
'32748', 'Team 3', 'L', '2019-02-16 19:20:00'
'32748', 'Team 4', 'W', '2019-02-16 19:20:00'
```

I've adapted a query I found here that calculates streaks using that table and shows me the Team, Start date of the streak, end date, streak count and the matches that are included in that streak.

```
'Team 1', '1992-07-05', '1992-09-06', '5', '9522,9142,9161,9167,9180'
```

The problem I have is that I have to include the team name in a where clause or the query shows incorrect results. Here is the query I'm using for Winning Streaks

```
select 
   team_name,
   min(match_date) as start_date,
   max(match_date) as end_date,
   count(match_date) as streak,
   group_concat(idmatch) as gameid_list
from
( 
  select *,      
    IF(
        result = "W"
        and 
        @result = "W", 
           @gn, @gn := @gn + 1)                
    as group_number,

    @match_date as old_date, @idmatch as old_gameid, 
    @result as old_rersult,

    @match_date := match_date, @idmatch := idmatch, 
    @result := result    
  from my_football_database.`Resultados Globales WDL`
  cross join 
  (
    select 
      @match_date := CAST(null as date) as xa,
      @idmatch := null + 0 as xb,
      @result := null + 0 as xc, @gn := 0
  ) x where team_name = "Team 1"
  order by match_date
) as y
group by group_number
order by streak desc;
```

As you can see, I have to specify the name of the team in a where clause so If I want to get for example the top 3 winning streaks in history, I have to run this query 150 times for each team, and then manually compare.

How can I modify this to get a full list of streaks correctly grouped by teams?

Comment: It's hard to say without all the information but I'm pretty sure that adding `team_name` to the `order by match_date` (i.e. `order by team_name, match_date`) clause will solve your problem; that will ensure that the matches are processed team by team instead of mixed according to date only.

Comment: Or we could just hold out for all the information (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I feel like an idiot, that was it. I was managing all sorting from my view but was altering it here. That fixed it, thanks @Nick

Comment: @MatiasDiez that's cool. Glad you got it working.